# SQL - group by condition using dates from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables say `AccountHistory` and `AccessHistory`. `AccountHistory` table contains details about when a customer was activated (only once). Similarly the `AccessHistory` table contains details when the customer logged into our site(multiple times).

AccountHistory :

```
ID  HistoryDt  CustomerID
--  ---------  ----------
1   2016-01-02          1
2   2016-02-01          2
```

AccessHistory :

```
ID  AccessDt  CustomerID
--  ---------  ----------
1   2016-01-02          1
2   2016-02-01          2
3   2016-02-05          2
4   2016-03-06          1
```

I want to write a query to generate a report that shows how many `new` customers logged into the site in a particular month.

For example from the above tables, the Customer 2 has activated in February and he logged in twice. Also customer 1 has been activated in January and also logged in March.

So the output would be

```
 NewUsersAccess      Month
 -------------       -----
             1          1
             2          2
             0          3
```

Since I am new to SQL, I can only think of writing a crude query using subqueries like this:

```
select COUNT(*) from AccessHistory 
where CustomerID in 
(select DISTINCT(CustomerID) from AccountHistory where HistoryDt > '2015-12-31' 
and HistoryDt < '2016-02-01') and AccessDt > '2015-12-31' 
and AccessDt < '2016-02-01'
```

But it can only fetch data for month at a time. Can someone please suggest a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
select year(ath.historyDt), month(ath.historyDt), count(ath.CustomerId)
from AccountHistory ath left join
     AccessHistory ah
     on ah.CustomerID = ath.CustomerID and
        ah.accessDt >= ath.historyDt and
        ah.accessDt < dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(ath.historyDt))
group by year(ath.historyDt), month(ath.historyDt);
```

Note that the date arithmetic uses the `eomonth()` function to get the last date of the month -- and then add one more day for the inequality.

Also:  This will only include months where customers actually start.  Getting the "0" values is a slightly different problem that would make a query a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes! This solves my issue. I was intially confused as the Date columns where reversed in you query. But after correcting it, it resolves my issue.Thanks!

Comment: @nitinvertigo . . . The names confused me too ("access" is too similar to "account" in the morning).  The `left join` should start with the history table, not the access table.  I think it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and sorry about the names .One small question. Shouldn't we be getting the date from the AccessHistory table since it contains the records for the customer's access details. In the first line of the query it is ah.historyDt and in the group by also it is ath.HistoryDt. Please correct me if I am wrong.